# JSF and Ajax request example

Tags: ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am working with JSF 2.2 with primefaces I want to try the following exemple like first page of Facebook.
I have a `textarea` and a buttton where a person can write a publication, what I want to do is that the previous publications selected from database should be there and if he add a new publication it will be added directly with Ajax.

My `textarea` is like that:

```
         <h:inputTextarea value="#{Acceuil.contenu}" styleClass="form-control">    
         </h:inputTextarea>
```

Could you help me figure it out?

Comment: Hey, I dont know how exacly it is to do with only jsf. I always work with primefaces (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml) and it has a awesome ajax engine. Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

First, please attach all the relevant code when asking a question, we see nothing but a text area, no buttons, no posts!

Have you looked at [`f:ajax` tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) ?

Anyways it's simple what you want to do. You must be having a "posts" fragement or something, which i assume it reads the posts from a `List`. So you add the new post to the `List` and then `render` the "posts" area using `f:ajax`

I guess you found this tutorial when you googled "ajax jsf" : [JSF 2.0 + Ajax Hello World Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-ajax-hello-world-example)
. It's all what you need